Should the untagged tag exist?
I recently noticed a tag called Untagged. I fail to see the purpose of a tag to state that there are no tags (which, by adding the tag, is rendered false) rather than adding or making a tag that fits the question? Should it be deleted?

When a question migrates from a different site, the tags don't migrate because the tags are not there to begin with in the destination site. Generally, such migration are blocked, but if a mod do it, such checks are bypassed. Hence the question gets untagged or tagged with a tag called untagged (note that the tag itself is blacklisted and cannot be used separately). It is the site users to verify the question and put appropriate tags.
